# How to disable loggers from class or a package which is from external jar

Tags: java, selenium, logging

External jar ***selenium-server-2.42.2*** is included to my java project.
I want to disable the logging from some of the classes of this external jar
I added below line in ***log4j.properties*** file

```
log4j.logger.org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver=OFF
```

But still logs are displayed on a console as below

> 13:08:36.283 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.xpath:
>   //div[contains(@class,'loading-spinner')]])

Answer (score 0):

Create a log4j.xml file to override the defaults in the 3rd party jar (an .xml file overrites property files). Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration>
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
      value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="PACKAGE_TO_DISABLE">
    <priority value="off"/>
</category>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

In your case the package could be org.openqa.selenium! Or you have to try some values to get the right package!

Comment: Where to add <category name="PACKAGE_TO_DISABLE">
    <priority value="off"/>
</category>

Comment: Its as good as below line added in log4j.properties. log4j.logger.org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver=OFF What the difference in keeping log4j.properties and log4j.xml?

Comment: My log4j.property file is as below

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=INFO, consoleAppender, fileAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Comment: log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=ui_automation.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=2 
log4j.logger.com.bmc.arsys=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver=ERROR

Comment: try to replace `<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">`

if you replace

`<root>
        <priority value="off"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>`

there are still log messages or not?